# Bluemix IoT NodeJS code, missing MQTT folder

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, iot

I am new to Bluemix and IoT. Earlier I replicated Parking Lot App as shown in the document on [link](https://iotwb.mybluemix.net/images/pdfFiles/IoT_Workbench_Tutorial_NodeJS_v1.2.pdf). that time the app worked fine. Now when i try to replicate the same app again I see the code structure is changed. the "mqtt" folder which was there previously is missing/omitted from the code. I am unable to find the callbacks which were there in files under "mqtt" folder.
I checked the above mentioned doc if its modified, but it is still the old doc which is there since March.

can someone guide me on this?

folder structure before :

[image]

folder stucture after :

[image]

Comment: I tested and didn't get MQTT folder created.  I am checking with dev team to see if something changed with the base code.

Answer (score 2):

IoT-Workbench now uses new improved code generation scheme for node.js.
Older applications that used the old code the workbench will still use the old scheme and will not be affected.
The document of the parking finder sample will be updated in the next few days for reflect the changes.

The new scheme introduce many improvements like:
-Simpler handling of mqtt events and commands,
-Simpler handling of http messages
- More options to add user code

Comment: is there some video or document that elaborates the new code and how to handle the mqtt events? or we have to wait for few days to see any of the doc/tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

We updated the Node.js tutorial - please access it via the all solutions page (the page that opens when you launch the service)
Let us know if you have any feedback.