# MQTT settings not getting reflected if they are changed after deploying the code on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot

I created an app under IoT on Bluemix. I added a key and an auth token under the MQTT settings and then deployed the application. Now due to some reason I changed the access key, updated the key and token in the MQTT settings, and delivered the code. However, the new key isn't reflected in the VCAP_SERVICES variable. It still shows the old key and token values.

Is this an expected behaviour or a bug?
Is there a solution or workaround for this issue?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the app and where you are updating the MQTT settings? Did you follow a tutorial that you can provide link?

Comment: @ValerieLampkin I followed [this link](https://iotwb.mybluemix.net/images/pdfFiles/IoT_Workbench_Tutorial_NodeJS_v1.2.pdf), its the default tutorial given on Bluemix.

Answer (score 1):

Per this other [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108897/bluemix-iot-nodejs-code-missing-mqtt-folder), that tutorial is being updated.

IoT-Workbench now uses new improved code generation scheme for node.js. The document should be updated in the next few days for reflect the changes.

I will ask Avraham if he has any further update.

Comment: mentioned question is also asked by me :)
and as far as the documentation goes it is still not updated.

Comment: I notified the development contact Avraham that you would like details.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug but expected behaviour.

The api key in "MQTT settings" is used by the workbench to create and register virtual devices in the IoT-Platform service that is bound to the application.

The application will always take the credentials of the bound IoT-Platform service from VCAP_SERVICES.